# Update newly inserted records id to another table using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario where I have to insert the record into the table, take the id of the inserted record and update a second table (with some other properties)

Here is code sample:

```
public void UpdateLookupDetails()
{
    string newId;            

    {
        //Add new record
        newId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var newRefUiRecord = new Entities.REFUILBLTXT
        {
            ID = newId,
            ACTIVEFLG = Constant.Flag.Yes,
            CRTTS = DateTime.Now,
            CRTUID = "cfbc94a9-16a5-11e1-8a27-a2e9ab9c0b63",
            LBLTXT = "Description",
            LOCALECD = Constant.LanguageCode.English,
            MODTS = DateTime.Now,
            MODUID = "cfbc94a9-16a5-11e1-8a27-a2e9ab9c0b63",
            LBLCD = "LookupList.DESC"
        };                
        _context.REFUILBLTXTs.Add(newRefUiRecord);                
    }

    var sample = _context.ZREFLISTs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == "e8ae24b1-029c-44d2-a413-c25c19189751");
    _context.ZREFLISTs.Attach(sample);
    sample.REFLISTDESCLBLID = newId;
    _context.Entry(sample).Property(x => x.REFLISTDESCLBLID).IsModified = true;

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As of now, application stuck at `_context.SaveChanges();` When running from Integration Test cases after a minute or so it gives an error saying

```
TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

If I comment out `_context.REFUILBLTXTs.Add(newRefUiRecord);` **OR** `_context.ZREFLISTs.Attach(sample);` It works! So its only updating or inserting records at a time.

Can anyone shed light on what the problem is here?

Environment: Web API 2 + Oracle EF + code first

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stuck"?  What is the definition for ZRefList? My guess based on what you are trying to do is that the RefListDescLblId is a FK to this RefUiLblTxt entity? If the ZRefList entity has both a FK field and a reference to one of these RefUiLblTxt entities, then you will want to update that reference to your new entity, not simply change the FK value. That naming convention seems pretty inconsistent, you might also look at giving the entities meaningful names and mapping the table/column names via configuration.

Comment: @StevePy : It gives an error saying the task was canceled. I know database structure is messed up but we don't own the database schema, so can't help it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try by removing the **attach** statement and try like below :

```
var sample = _context.ZREFLISTs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == "e8ae24b1-029c-44d2-a413-c25c19189751");
sample.REFLISTDESCLBLID = newId;
_context.Entry(sample).State = EntityState.Modified;
```